# Email Tracking using asp.net

Tags: c#

I want to track users who have read my mails.I am doing this but it's not working
 I am sending mails to myself in outlook.
 Here is my code which sends mails

```
  try
        {

        string emailTemplateBody = "Hy this is test mail";
        emailTemplateBody += "<tr><img src=''http://localhost:52583/HttpModule_using_beacon_images/images/<keyvalue>.aspx''  style=''opacity:0.0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);'' /></tr>";



        string templateName = txtTemplateName.Text;

                    string toEmail = mymailaddress

        //// Get unique Key after registring mail to be sent
        string key = bl_email_calls.RegisterSystemEmailAudit("1", templateName, DateTime.Now);
        emailTemplateBody = emailTemplateBody.Replace("<keyvalue>", key);
        //// sending e-mail
        bl_email_calls.SendMailMessage(toEmail, templateName, emailTemplateBody, key);
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
           //code to insert record in database;            }
        Response.Write("Mail sent");
        // return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
```

Here is my HTTP module i have used from http://www.aspnetemail.com/samples/emailtracker/default.aspx[^]

```
public class HttpModuleClass : IHttpModule
{
    //public event EventHandler BeginRequest;

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// public varibles
    /// </summary>
    string footerFile = "~/images/footer.png";
    //string footerFile = "~/images/ajax-loader.gif";
    Email_Calls bl_email_calls = new Email_Calls();

    /// <summary>
    /// Init methoed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new System.EventHandler(GetImage_BeginRequest);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// handles requests made to server and call update email read time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public void GetImage_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        //cast the sender to a HttpApplication object
        System.Web.HttpApplication application = (System.Web.HttpApplication)sender;

        string url = application.Request.Path; //get the url path
        //string pattern = @"/HttpModule/images/(?<key>.*)\.aspx";
        //string pattern = @"/HttpModule_using_beacon_images/images/(?<key>.*)\.aspx";

        string pattern = @"/HttpModule_using_beacon_images/images/(?<key>.*)\.aspx";
        //string pattern = @"~/images/(?<key>.*)\.aspx";
        //create the regex to match for beacon images
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (r.IsMatch(url))
        {
            MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(url);
            if ((mc != null) && (mc.Count > 0))
            {
                string key = (mc[0].Groups["key"].Value);
                bl_email_calls.UpdateSystemEmailAuditReadDate(key);

            }

            //now send the REAL image to the client
            //application.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
            application.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

            application.Response.WriteFile(application.Request.MapPath(footerFile));

            //end the response
            application.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Outlook will block images in mails for non-trusted senders, or for senders that the user has not enabled the option to display images, primarily to prevent this kind of tracking. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-e-mail-messages-HP001230040.aspx for example

Comment: Why the escape for apostrophe? ie `...src=''http:...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I was making some little mistakes.

Actually I was saving the email body into the database so I had to use `''` instead of `'` and that was making all the trouble. When is removed '' it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

To request a read receipt, we need add a custom header named `'Disposition-Notification-To'`
in this example, read receipts will go back to 'someaddress@mydomain.com'
it's important to note that read receipts will only be sent by those mail clients that 
a) support them
and
b)have them enabled.

//Add `"Disposition-Notification-To"` for Read receipt

```
  mail.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "<mail@yahoo.com>");
```